# My indexes don't appear

Tags: makeindex

```
This is my problem: I have two indexes which don't appear, nor in the TOC, nor in the end of my document when I compile my file. My MWE:
\documentclass{book}

    \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=npr, title=Index des noms cités] 
\makeindex[name=mat, title=Index des matières]

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{Tufte2002,
 author = {Tufte, Blabla},
 year = {2002},
 title = {A title},
 
}
\end{filecontents}
    
\begin{document}
    
\cite{Tufte2002} \index[npr]{Tufte}\index[mat]{Data}

    \bibnewpage 
{%start grouping
  \doublespacing % <====================================================
  \raggedright 
  \nocite{}
  \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
    \bibliography{mabibliocrc}
}%end grouping

\phantomsection
\cleardoublepage
\printindex[npr] 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index des noms cités}
\printindex[mat]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index des matières}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please first of all to never ignore compilation errors. Are you by any chance using overleaf? The command `\doublespacing` is not defined by default. Removing it makes the example compile for me and it seems to make the two indices.

Comment: I don't use Overleaf. And removing \doublespacing does not change anything.

Comment: Then please explain how you compile this example. Which latex installation, which editor. Do you get any errors? Preferably provide the log from a compilation on your side of this exact MWE (with `\doublespacing` removed)

Comment: I use Mac Tex 2021 on Mac Os Big Sur with Texpad. This is what I get after compiling: "LaTeX Warning: Citation `Tufte2002' undefined on input line 22.
"

Comment: Please post the log file, don't trust what ever filtered log the editor gives you. When I look in my log after running `pdflatex` it explicitly states that it is running `makeindex` as a part of the compilation.

Comment: I have no problem compiling if I remove `\doublespacing` and change the bibliography to use mybib.bib. I compile using pdflatex, bibtex, makeindex npr.idx, makeindex mat.idx and finally two runs of pdflatex.

Comment: Obviously, it works with TexShop, but not using Texpad.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{setspace}` and correct to `\bibliography{mybib.bib}`.  Works fine with pdflatex and lualatex. So the problem lies in the TeXtpad configuration. Could you do the multiple runs required from the command line?

Comment: @SimonDispa: setspace is already set. I don't know why, but now it works as usual. Is the message I sent today to the support team for anything in that? Whatever, I won't have to change of text editor!